# How to access attributes of the widgets children

Tags: flutter, dart

I am opening a new activity with the `startTimer` method How do I set the `cyclesVal` variable to an attribute of my custom `NumberSelector` widget so I can pass it to the next activity. Any way to access an internal variable of the `NumberSelector` widget would work too since I have set the attribute to the variable.

```
class ExcersizeInput extends StatelessWidget {
  const ExcersizeInput({super.key});

  void startTimer(BuildContext context) {
    int cyclesVal = 1;
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => TimerPage(
            cycleCount: cyclesVal,
          ),
        ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      Column(
        children: [
          NumberSelector(
            title: "Cycles",
          ),
        ],
      ),
      ElevatedButton.icon(
        onPressed: (() => {startTimer(context)}),
        label: const Text("Start"),
        icon: const Icon(Icons.start_outlined),
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```

Here's the NumberSelector code:

```
class NumberSelector extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;


  const NumberSelector(
      {super.key, required this.title});

  @override
  State<NumberSelector> createState() => _NumberSelectorState();
}

class _NumberSelectorState extends State<NumberSelector> {
  int selectorValue = 1;

  void updateValue(ifAdd) {
    setState(() {
      if (ifAdd) {
        if (selectorValue < 9999) {
          selectorValue++;
        }
      } else {
        if (selectorValue > 1) {
          selectorValue--;
        }
      }
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ColorScheme colors = Theme.of(context).colorScheme;
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(widget.title,
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        Row(
          children: [
            GestureDetector(
              child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () => updateValue(false),
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.remove),
                  style: styleContainedButton),
              },
            ),
            Text(selectorValue.toString()),
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
            GestureDetector(
              child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () => updateValue(true),
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                  style: styleContainedButton),
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: could you include NumberSelector code too?

Comment: sure but keep in mind it will not be the full code as it is extensive

Comment: For me it's not clear what you want :D

Comment: I want the eqivalent of 'int cyclesVal = widget.child[0].child[0].child[1].child[0].selectorValue' but not in pseudocode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a variable from a stateful widget in flutter it needs a key that is linked to the state of the widget. Via the key, the variables can be accessed.

Define a widget you want to access from its parent and that contains any value:

```
class TestWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  TestWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestWidget> createState() => TestWidgetState();
}

class TestWidgetState extends State<TestWidget> {
  int? anyvalue;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Declare the key in the parent widget. Make sure the name of the state does not start with an underscore:

```
GlobalKey<TestWidgetState> _widget_key = GlobalKey();
```

Give the key to the widget in the build method of the parent widget:

```
TestWidget(
   key: _widget_key,
)
```

Now the value of the child widget can be accessed in the parent widget via the key:

```
void afunction() {
  print(_widget_key.currentState!.anyvalue);
}
```